# Ruby on Rails 4 select schema_migrations Error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Guy today i was open old Ruby project 
after copy the files to my Sites folder then run this commands

```
bundle
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
rails s
```

when i was open my project on the browser i found the project gives me errors because 
MySQL not work with me  also i got this error on the console

```
ActiveRecord::SchemaMigation Load (68.0ms) select 'schema_migrations'.* from 'schema_migrations'
processing by HomeController#index as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 92ms
log writing faild. invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII
```

so why i got this error and how i can solve that ??

Comment: I don't see any error. Can you share the complete error stacktrace in the question and not part of it.

Comment: when i open my application from the Bowers i got this error 
[ We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.] 
but in the console screen i found this error
  
could not determine content-lenght of response body. set content-lenght of the response or set Response#chunked = true
processing by HomeController#index as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 92ms
log writing faild. invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII

Answer (score 0):

I solved it now

just to solve the **US-ASCII**  issue 
i added this line to the first line in my model  page

```
#encoding: utf-8
```

also i added the lines

```
if RUBY_VERSION =~ /1.9/
    Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
    Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
end
```

in my Gemfile

then i got another error  told me use `protected_attributes`

so i added the line

```
gem 'protected_attributes'
```

in my Gemfile and then execute:

```
$ bundle
```